# How to load and display local image in Three20

Tags: iphone, three20, photo-gallery

Now I am  on Three20..  I am using Two image source for loading image..That means

One Type of image from LOcal folder.ie from application folder
Other is from url..
My problem is i dont know how to load image from local folder..and display it...

My code is  given below...

```
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:mpngPath];
    if(fileExists==YES)
    {

        NSLog(@"image is present");

        //load and display??


    }


    else {
        NSLog(@"image is  not present");
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the url with your photo path. I assume that you save your images in your document directory.

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"documents://%@",yourPhotoName];
```